# calling repaint() from a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, repaint

I'm just trying to figure out how Threads work (i.e. I'm a beginner). This program does not serve any purpose other than this.

However, it does not work as intended. My goal was make a the Circle brighter and brighter so that it disappears in the background. But the repaint() call in the Thread does not seem to work.

Here is my code:

```
public class Run {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Circle();
    }
}


import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Circle extends JFrame implements Runnable {

    private boolean running = false;
    private Thread t;
    Color currentColor;
    int currentRed, currentGreen, currentBlue;

    public Circle() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,150));
        start();
        repaint();
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
            //super.paint(g);
            //currentColor = g.getColor();
            //currentRed = currentColor.getRed();
            //currentGreen = currentColor.getGreen();
            //currentBlue = currentColor.getBlue(); 
            g.setColor(new Color(currentRed++,currentGreen++,currentBlue++));
            g.fillOval(7,30,100,100);
    }


public synchronized void stop() {
    running = false;
    t.interrupt();
}

public synchronized void start() {
    System.out.println("start");
    if (!running) {
        running = true;
        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }

}

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(running) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5);
                System.out.println("run");
                repaint();
                System.out.println("repaint");   
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
        }
        }
    }

}
```

I also tried to call paint() instead, but I'm aware that I shouldn't do this and it didn't work anyways. It kind of makes sense to me. But it is unclear to me, why repaint doen't work...

Comment: you're sleeping 5ms, you must be looking pretty fast for the circle to disappear

Comment: repaint() is missing?? show us

Comment: @YatiSawhney repaint() calls paint() doesn't it?

Comment: @ThomasJungblut I also tried with Thread.sleep(500) and Thread.sleep(1000) and it didn't work...

Comment: are you getting any exceptions?

Comment: You're setting the color of the graphics *after* you've painted the oval. Do it *before*. Replace the body of the paint method by `g.setColor(new Color(currentRed++, currentGreen++, currentBlue++));
        g.fillOval(7, 30, 100, 100);`

Comment: @YatiSawhney No, I just see a black Circle which doesn't update, i.e. it doen't change its color/doen't fade away...

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks, this makes a lot of sense... but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I think I was also missing a super.paint(g) call, but I added it and simplified the code (I start with a specific color (black) now), but it still doesn't work...

Comment: Yes, it does. I've just tested it. Post a complete minimal example (and I mean complete: I must be able to copy and paste the code and execute it, without having to do any modification whatsoever), tell precisely what you expect to happen and what happens instead. "doesn't work" is much too vague.

Comment: @JBNizet I've changed the code in my question above as you suggested. This does not work for me. In my main, I just have new Circle(); nothing else.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data to replace the DB. 2) Use a Swing `Timer` to call `repaint()`. 3) Better to do custom painting in a `JPanel` that is added to a `JFrame`. It is double buffered by default. The correct method to override for a panel (or any `JComponent`) is the `paintComponent(Graphics)` method, rather than `paint(..)`.

Comment: @JBNizet - nobody seemed to have put the link for an `[mre]` so added it. But yes, agree that a complete (but minimal) runnable example would be helpful here.

Comment: OK. So now it's clear. You haven't done what I told you to do: *Replace the body of the paint method by `g.setColor(new Color(currentRed++, currentGreen++, currentBlue++)); g.fillOval(7, 30, 100, 100);`*. There are only two lines of code here. Your code has 6.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I added my main. I'm sorry, I don't know what is not minimal in my example. As I said I'm just trying to figure out how Threads (with paint/repaint) work, and this program serves no other purpose so I tried to build it as minimal as possible from the beginning. I could delete the System.out... for sure, but they are useful in my opinion to see that at least something works... i.e. at least my Thread seems to do what it is supposed to do but the not the repaint. Maybe repaint is waiting that the Thread has finished??

Comment: Again: Replace the body of the paint method by `g.setColor(new Color(currentRed++, currentGreen++, currentBlue++)); g.fillOval(7, 30, 100, 100);`. There are only two lines of code here. Your code has 6.

Comment: @JBNizet I did try that! I tried again, just to be extra sure. It doesn't work. I have Windows. It doesn't make much sense if I now also change the above code, right?

Comment: Again, edit your question, and post the **actual** code you tried.

Comment: @JBNizet OK, so in my opinion this should give a NullPointerException because currentRed, currentGreen etc. is not initialized. But it doesn't. It also doen't work, though...

Comment: Instance fields are always initialized to their default values (false, 0, null). Assuming that "it doesn't work" means "the color of the circle never changes", I can't reproduce the issue on my OS and my JDK version. The code doesn't respect the best swing and threading practices though, so it might be an issue with that. Read the above comments by Andrew. Otherwise, maybe someone with the same JDK and OS that yours (you should post the information) can help you.

Comment: Ok, anyways. Thanks a lot for your help. I know that I have a lot to learn!

Comment: Remember, all code that changes the GUI **must** run on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) (EDT). From the code you posted, it looks like you are calling `repaint()` from a `Thread` you created - which is **not** the EDT.

Answer (score 2):

The following is a working version of your code. Note the comments:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Circle extends JFrame implements Runnable {

    private boolean running = false;
    private Thread t;
    int currentRed = 0, currentGreen = 0, currentBlue = 0;

    public Circle() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,150));
        //repaint(); //not really needed here
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
        start();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(new Color(currentRed,currentGreen,currentBlue));
        g.fillOval(7,30,100,100);
        //modify color and make sure it is valid
        currentRed = ++currentRed % 256;
        currentGreen = ++currentGreen % 256; //Equivalent to: currentGreen = currentGreen == 255 ? 0 : currentGreen+1;
        currentBlue = ++currentBlue % 256;
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        running = false;
        t.interrupt();
    }

    public synchronized void start() {
        if (!running) {
            running = true;
            t = new Thread(this);
            t.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(running) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5);
                repaint();
            } catch(InterruptedException e) { //do not mute exceptions  
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new Circle());
    }
}
```

A better implementation incorporating many of the tips you got in comments would be:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Circle extends JPanel { //do custom painting on a JPanel

    private boolean running = false;
    private int currentRed = 0, currentGreen = 0, currentBlue = 0;
    private final Timer timer; //use swing tools to update gui
    private static final int DELAY = 5, W = 100, H = 100, OFFSET = 25;

    public Circle() {
        timer = new Timer(DELAY, e -> repaint());
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(W + 2*OFFSET,H + 2*OFFSET));
    }

    public static void createAndShowGui(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Circle circle = new Circle();
        frame.add(circle);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        circle.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { //for custom painting override paintComponent
        super.paintComponent(g); //always call super
        g.setColor(new Color(currentRed,currentGreen,currentBlue));
        g.fillOval(OFFSET,OFFSET,W,H);
        //modify color and make sure it is valid
        currentRed = ++currentRed % 256;
        currentGreen = ++currentGreen % 256;
        currentBlue = ++currentBlue % 256;
    }

    public void stop() {
        running = false;
        timer.stop();
    }

    public void start() {
        if (!running) {
            running = true;
            timer.start();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```